# How can I import data from XML file int a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a task to import data from an XML file into my SQL Server table. When I open it in Excel 2007, I can see all the columns and rows of data from the XML file. This is perfect.

I then went into SQL and created my table to load the data into.

Since I did not have a schema file for my XML table, I went into Visual Studios 2012 and used to XML tool to create a schema file against my XML table.

I wrote a small vb script to try and do a bulk load from my XML to my SQL Server table, but having difficulty.

I am getting an error:

> Schema: relationship expected on 'General_segment'

Please help.
Mike Ayuso

Comment: how is anyone suppose to help you with what you've provided???

Comment: Well.. you have flagged SQL-server.  What version?  If microsoft sql server 2005 or after, you can use the sql server import / export wizard to pull directly from excel into a table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using google videos for your help... there are tons of videos showing how to do this step by step [GOOGLE](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=a9DzU4KOI4HY8ge8nICwAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=import%20xml%20into%20MS%20sql&tbm=vid)